# npm update -g does nothing even though I have outdated packages

Tags: node.js, windows, npm, windows-10, package-managers

I am running npm version 3.6.0 and node verison 5.6.0 on Windows 10:

```
> npm version
{ npm: '3.6.0',
  ares: '1.10.1-DEV',
  http_parser: '2.6.1',
  icu: '56.1',
  modules: '47',
  node: '5.6.0',
  openssl: '1.0.2f',
  uv: '1.8.0',
  v8: '4.6.85.31',
  zlib: '1.2.8' }
>
```

I have a number of globally installed npm packages:

```
> npm ls -g --depth=0
C:\Users\Klas\AppData\Roaming\npm
+-- bower@1.7.7
+-- generator-gulp-angular@1.0.2
+-- generator-gulp-angular-subtask@0.9.1
+-- gulp@3.9.1
+-- jspm@0.16.25
+-- karma-cli@0.1.2
+-- live-server@0.9.0
+-- protractor@3.0.0
+-- tsd@0.6.5
+-- tslint@3.2.2
+-- typescript@1.7.5
+-- webpack@1.12.11
+-- webpack-dev-server@1.14.1
`-- yo@1.6.0

>
```

If I run `npm outdated -g` several packages are listed as outdated.

```
> npm outdated -g
Package      Current   Wanted   Latest  Location
jspm         0.16.25  0.16.25  0.16.29
live-server    0.9.0    0.9.0    0.9.2
protractor     3.0.0    3.0.0    3.1.1
tslint         3.2.2    3.2.2    3.4.0
webpack      1.12.11  1.12.11  1.12.13
```

When I run `npm update -g` it returns (after a couple of seconds) without any warning or error message. However, no packages have been updated.

```
> npm update -g
>
```

As I interpret [this issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/6247), `npm update -g` should work, and should update top level global packages. But it doesn't seem to work for me.

If I run (thanks to Benjamin Kaiser for the tip):

```
> npm update -g --loglevel verbose
```

I get a lot of output. This seems to be the most relevant:

```
npm verb outdated not updating tslint because it's currently at the maximum version 
that matches its specified semver range
```

I still don't quite understand. Since the packages are global, there is no specified semver range?

Running update on a particular package does not help either:

```
> npm update -g tslint
>
```

Not even specifying a version does any difference:

```
> npm update -g tslint@3.4.0
>
```

But even if that had worked I would rather not have to explicitly update each package. To me, a major feature of a package manager should be to make it easy to update everything at once.

[This issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/10590) sounds related. But when I look at the [tslint npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tslint) the "latest" seems to be 3.4.0. So why no upgrade?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `--loglevel verbose` flag to see if anything might be happening at a lower log level?

From everything you've said, your npm version should be up to date to run that command.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminKaiser, I extended my question with the results of setting that flag

Comment: That's super weird, you are right that it's global and as such shouldn't have a semver.

I'd maybe try wiping global packages an starting again. Maybe reinstalling npm also to the latest version (3.7.4 I think)

Comment: I second that. Looking through this, I've had similar issues and I've wiped and started over as well.

Answer (score 13):

`npm -g update` has, uh, pretty unexpected behaviour. This might be a suitable workaround:

```
$ npm -g outdated --parseable=true | cut -d : -f 4 | xargs -n 1 npm -g install
```

Comment: Thanks - this is a good workaround, and definitely does the same behaviour that I expect from `npm -g update`.

Comment: This answer could be greatly improved by elaborating what is `npm` behavior, what are implications of it and whether there is any way of changing it. Right now we have command that does fix the problem, but no real understanding of the issue.